# Using NextJS On Demand Revalidation on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, incremental-static-regeneration

We have built a NextJS website that is running on AWS Amplify, we are currently using getStaticProps in order to render the pages, and we generate them using getStaticPaths.

We would like to use on-demand revalidation in order to refresh the data on our command when we update the database, for example.

Our local env works perfectly, the data is the same until we change and revalidate using our secret API endpoint, on the other hand when we deploy to AWS Amplify, the revalidation doesn't work.

We looked into the logs and didn't see any errors, nor are the permissions for SQS invalid. We even removed the branch and redeployed it, yet nothing worked.

I have tried searching for the same problem online yet didn't find any solution, did anyone here stumble upon the same issue?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe features introduced in Next.js 12 onwards (including On-demand Revalidation) are not yet supported by AWS Amplify. See https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2343.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this isn't supported yet, and in the works by the Amplify team.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in an issue I opened on Amplify's GitHub:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3116

> right now, Amplify Hosting does not support on-demand ISR. Supporting
> it is on our roadmap and we will update our documentation to make this
> clear.

I'm using Vercel while they work on that.